# How to get HTTP status text from HTTP status code?

Tags: php, libcurl, php-7, guzzle

Is there any standard function (or in curl, Guzzle) to get a HTTP status text/description from a HTTP status code number?

```
getHttpStatusText(404) === 'Not Found'
```

I know that I can just create a map like

```
[
    ...
    404 => 'Not Found',
    ...
]
```

but I think there is should be already a standard function for that somewhere?

Comment: [Included with the method docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#107261).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in Guzzle (which is where I actually needed it):

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#using-responses

```
$response->getReasonPhrase()
```

Here is also the associative array with all statuses:

https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/12f6fcd48192c390c00856f5570335b9e6aab081/src/Response.php#L18